# Load raw memory blob in DPX format with Graphicsmagick

Tags: graphicsmagick

I have a library that generates a Big Endian 10-bit DPX image in a memory buffer.  It's just the raw 10-bit RGB data, though, with no headers.  I'm trying to load this data into an instance of `Magick::Image` like this:

```
Magick::Blob blob(dataBuffer, dataBufferSize;
image.read(blob, Magick::Geometry(width, height), 10 /*bits*/, "DPX");
```

This throws the following exception, though:  `Magick: Improper image header ()`

Is it possible to load a raw DPX into a `Magick::Image`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my own answer here.  I took a look at the DPX loading source and found out for this case this line:

```
image.read(blob, Magick::Geometry(width, height), 10 /*bits*/, "DPX");
```

should be:

```
image.read(blob, Magick::Geometry(width, height), 10 /*bits*/, "SDPX");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that your answer is a good one. It it is working by accident.  Your blob data is likely to be in some other format than DPX.  Specifying 'SDPX' (an unsupported format specification) allowed the file format detection to automatically work and select the correct format.

Using

```
enter code herMagick::Blob blob(dataBuffer, dataBufferSize);
image.read(blob);
```

should then be sufficient.  Most image file formats do not require specifying the format or the depth.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is pure RAW pixel data that just happens to be in DPX Big Endian format.  Nothing in the buffer itself will tell GraphicsMagick that it's 10-bit DPX.  There is no header, nothing that specifies image width or height.  Just pure pixel data.